# What ordinals correspond to tuples ordered lexicographically?

Tags: logic, set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

Consider the set $\mathbb{N}^k$ of $k$-tuples of natural numbers ordered lexicographically. This corresponds to the ordinal number $\omega^k$.

What ordinal number corresponds to $(n_1,\ldots,n_k) \in \mathbb{N}^k$?

I conjecture that $(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ corresponds to the ordinal $n_1 \cdot \omega^{k-1}+\ldots+ n_{k-1} \cdot \omega +n_k$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that ordinal multiplication is NOT commutative.

You don't want $n_{k-1} \cdot \omega$ because that equals $\omega$.

You should write

$$\omega^{k-1} \cdot n_1+\cdots+ \omega \cdot n_{k-1} +n_k$$